# Xcode Instruments CPU time

Tags: iphone, performance, xcode, instruments

if i run an application with the performance test, the "cpu monitor" show me some informations like process ID/Name or CPU Time. But in which unit of time does it measure ?

An example: if i get 05.04 , what does mean for me

Best Regards

Comment: see this:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_time

Answer (score 0):

Plagiarized from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_time -

CPU time (or CPU usage, process time) is the amount of time for which a central processing unit (CPU) was used for processing instructions of a computer program, as opposed to, for example, waiting for input/output (I/O) operations.
The CPU time is often **measured in clock ticks or seconds**. CPU time is also mentioned as percentage of the CPU's capacity at any given time on multi-tasking environment. That helps in figuring out how a CPU’s computational power is being shared among multiple computer programs.

Comment: if answer is only link, then add it to comments only

Comment: Not to be a nit pick - Editing an answer is another way to "Add more information" to an already acceptable answer.  Even short answers should be placed in the answer section (comments are for comments).  Down-voting a technically correct answer that wasn't posted in a way that you prefer (like link only) is not helpful to people who came here to look for an answer.  This answer has been expanded to show the detail requested. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144566/new-policy-on-link-only-answers